# How to find asymptotic of function s=s(n): s^s = n

Tags: asymptotics

How to find asymptotic of function s=s(n): $s^s = n$.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, what is your function again?

Comment: s^s = n, where s is a function of n.

Comment: I think yes. How did you get this?

Answer (score 1):

If $s\log s=\log n$, then $s\lt\log n$ for every $n\gt e^e$, because then $\log n\log\log n\gt\log n$. Likewise, for every $a\lt1$, $(\log n)^a\log(\log n)^a=a(\log n)^a\log\log n\ll\log n$, hence $s\gt(\log n)^a$ for every $n$ large enough.
This proves that 
$$
\log s\sim\log\log n.
$$
One can go further, plugging back into the relation $s\log s=n$ any available expansion of $s$ one has, to get a more precise one. This yields, for example,
$$
s=\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\,\left(1+\frac{\log\log\log n}{\log\log n}\,(1+o(1))\right).
$$

Comment: $a(\log n)^a\log\log n\ll\log n$



How did you get this? It does not seem right

Comment: Of course this holds. Could you prove that $\log\log n\ll(\log n)^b$ for every $b\gt0$?